# Menu and Toolbar font size in Webstorm 11

Tags: windows, webstorm, font-size

I'm running Webstorm 11 on Windows 10. I am able to adjust the font size and colors for the code editor window, but have not been able to change the font size in the menus. The project tree view is what I need to change in particular.

You can see the difference in font sizes here. I'd like them to be the same.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Font used for menus and toolbars can be adjusted in `Settings | Appearance & Behavior |  Appearance`, `Override default fonts by`